# Creating cron job to fetching twitter posts from user's wall using spring-social

Tags: spring, twitter, cron, job-scheduling, spring-social

I'm trying to create a cron job, which should fetch logged user's tweets.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
    public class MessagesSaver {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(MessagesSaver.class);
private static String TWITTER_NETWORK = "twitter";
private static String FACEBOOK_NETWORK = "facebook";
private static int MAX_TWEET_COUNT_PER_PAGE = 50;
@Autowired
private MessageRepository messageRepository;
@Autowired
private Twitter twitter;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 * * * *")
public void getMessagesFromSocialNetworks() {
    if (twitter != null) {
        List<Tweet> tweets = twitter.timelineOperations().getUserTimeline(
                MAX_TWEET_COUNT_PER_PAGE);
        parseAndSaveTwitterPosts(tweets);
    }
}
}
```

and SocialConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //
    // SocialConfigurer implementation methods
    //

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig,
            Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(env
                .getProperty("twitter.consumerKey"), env
                .getProperty("twitter.consumerSecret")));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                return "admin";
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(
            ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource,
                connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
    }



    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Twitter twitter(ConnectionRepository repository) {
        Connection<Twitter> connection = repository
                .findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }

    //
    // Web Controller and Filter Beans
    //
    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(
            ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        ConnectController connectController = new ConnectController(
                connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
        return connectController;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(
            ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator,
                usersConnectionRepository, new SimpleSignInAdapter(
                        new HttpSessionRequestCache()));
    }

    @Bean
    public DisconnectController disconnectController(
            UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, Environment env) {
        return new DisconnectController(usersConnectionRepository,
                env.getProperty("facebook.clientSecret"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ReconnectFilter apiExceptionHandler(
            UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository,
            UserIdSource userIdSource) {
        return new ReconnectFilter(usersConnectionRepository, userIdSource);
    }

}
```

But of course it doesn't work, because twitter connection live in the request scope(
How i can configure this job?

Answer (score 1):

The logged in user is associated with a web session, so there's no problem obtaining a request-scoped Twitter object at the web level of your app.

However, scheduled/cron jobs operate independent of the web layer of your application. They have no concept of "logged in user", as they are simply background beans, similar to services or DAOs in that they have no concept of who the current user is. From the perspective of MessagesSaver, who is the logged in user? There could easily be *many* logged in users. Which one is it expected to work on behalf of?

You could inject a UsersConnectionRepository into MessagesSaver, use it to obtain a ConnectionRepository for a specific user, then use that to obtain the Twitter connection (and from that, the Twitter API binding). The tricky bit is (again) who is the logged in user? There could be many...which one is MessagesSaver supposed to use?

Stepping away from what you've written here, what is it that your trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer)
There are should be only 1 user, which will be logged into twitter.

Comment: i'm trying to explain what i want to do)
i have 1 twitter account and want to fetch new tweet of this user(or get tweets by hash tag) by job and put it into database. That's all.

Comment: when i try to do exactly how you say("You could inject a UsersConnectionRepository into MessagesSaver, use it to obtain a ConnectionRepository for a specific user, then use that to obtain the Twitter connection (and from that, the Twitter API binding)"), I receive exception:
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.connectionRepository': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;